# Explain the concept of branch, trunk, in the context of source code repositories (like Subversion, VCS, VSS)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

concept of branch, trunk/* 
Context of Source Code repositories

Answer (score 0):

A trunk is the main code base and is the one that began when the project started and until the present.

A branch is a copy of the code derived from trunk and that is used for applying changes to the code. If the changes are accepted, they are merged back into the trunk.